# UIScrollView absolute position

Tags: swift, storyboard

I have so problem and question. How to assign an absolute size and position for my UIScrollView. I did constraints and alignment constraints, but on the other iPhone position of my UIScrollView changes and they are didn't work as like as I want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Размер и положение ScrollView зависит от элементов, которые в нем расположены. Если их констрейнты установлены правильно, то ScrollView будет работать. Вот статья на эту тему: https://fluffy.es/scrollview-storyboard-xcode-11/